# Angular2 routing with Asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

I need a help.
I start to develop angular2 with Asp.net core and everything was perfect. 
For redirecting all 404 request to index.html I use this code in Startup class.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });
```

But, I need to return to asp.net 4.5 and I have now a big problem with routing. I try to use similar code in Owin Startup class but that didn't resolve a problem.

How to move all request to index.html? 
One example: I have link which redirect to /logout, but with this code now app.module don't see /logout and I get redirected to home page of app.

In tutorial how to use angular2 with asp 4.5 (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)
 in last paragraph says:

> If this application used the Angular router, a browser refresh could
>   return a 404 - Page Not Found. Look at the address bar. Does it
>   contain a navigation url (a "deep link") ... any path other than / or
>   /index.html?
>
> You'll have to configure the server to return index.html for these
>   requests. Until you do, remove the navigation path and refresh again.

How to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect everything to the index.html page to solve this issue, here's the configuration code I used in one of my project:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectEverything" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Add this under the the `system.websever` section in your web.config

Comment: seconded...just found this as I have to use 4.5 with a Vue app, and had similar code as the OP.  This worked awesome!